# Concatenate two columns and print the text in new column in python

Tags: python

I have a code which compares master file with host file and word in a column from host file is found in master file it will mark - is found as 'yes'. I am struck with a thing to make this script complete. Please help me with this as I am still a newbie in python. Thanks in advance.

1. I wanted to concatenate two columns and print it in new column like below. I tried it but not able to fit in the code.

'''

```
 a       b      c
 mike   1334   mike1334
```

2. To make the comparing column case insensitive as both columns have upper and lower case values. the current code is case sensitive.

Main code used for comparing CSV files:

```
import csv


with open('master.csv', 'rt', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as master:
master_indices = dict((r[0], i) for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(master)))

with open('host.csv', 'rt', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as hosts:
    with open('result.csv', 'w', newline='') as results:    
        reader = csv.reader(hosts)
        writer = csv.writer(results)


        writer.writerow(next(reader, []) + ['Is found Yes/No'])

        for row in reader:

            index = master_indices.get(row[4])
            if index is not None:
                message = 'Yes'
                writer.writerow(row + [message])

            else:
                 message = 'No'
                 writer.writerow(row + [message])   


    results.close()
```

Output will be like this:

```
a       b      c         Is found
mike   1334   mike1334     yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy with PANDAS Library

```
import pandas as pd

master = pd.read_csv('master.csv',encoding= 'ISO-8859-1')
master['c'] = master['a']+master['b']
```

I think that you are expecting this only.